# Want to know how to find Modulo of a decimal number with 10^9 + 7?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, decimal, modulo

I was going through a coding competition. it asked there is **decimal number** and we have to find its modulo by **10^9 + 7(1000000007)**. the simple test cases were

1. **1.23** should give output **110000002**
2. **4.0** should give output **4**.

i was unable to understand how 1.23 can give that value. is decimal mod is treated in some different manner? not simply a remainder of a number.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice explanation about the data type sizes and their problems and also how to deal with modulo of exponential sizes.

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/abhinav92003/why-output-the-answer-modulo-109-7/

Comment: Hi kev, Thanks for writing back. i had already went through the formula provided there. and also implemented it. However i didnt got the desired result. 
however the following testcase is not successfull
1.23 should give output 110000002